# Invalid Arguments error in Global.asax in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-session

I`m trying to follow the tutorial [Securing Asp.net](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx) but when i try to put this line

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute());
```

it gives me a following error

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpFilterCollection.Add(System.Web.Http.Filters.IFilters)' has some invalid agruments
```

below is my Global.asax code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using DatabaseService_WebAPI.App_Start;

namespace DatabaseService_WebAPI
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new DatabaseService_WebAPI.Models.ProductContextInitializer());
            System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new DatabaseService_WebAPI.Models.LocalDBContextInitializer());
            System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new DatabaseService_WebAPI.Models.GCMClassContextInitializer());
            System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new DatabaseService_WebAPI.Models.ProductTypeContextInitializer());

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());

            WebApiConfig.Configure(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }

        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
            filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
            filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
        }
    }
}
```

I`m not an expert developer in mvc. so anyone can tell how to add filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create this method in global.asax.cs:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
   // add filters here
   filters.Add(new MyCustomFilter());
}
```

Then call it from the `Application_Start` method:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Comment: i`m trying to use  filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute()); in my global.asax but when i run my web page it display unable to connect. when i comment this line of code then it display the login page.

Comment: Sounds like a problem connecting to your site with HTTPS, check that you have the certificate installed correctly.