# HTTP to HTTPS redirection in mobile application using MVC 4 for some pages like sign-in, register

Tags: http, asp.net-mvc-4, https, controller

In My MVC4 Mobile application I have registration, login page and remaining pages. I would like to redirect user to HTTPS connection for all sensitive information pages like registration and login pages and HTTP to remailing pages.

For this, I used the following code: in the controller action method:

```
if (!HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection)
{
    var url = new UriBuilder(HttpContext.Request.Url);
    url.Scheme = "https";
    Response.Redirect(url.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

but getting this error:

> Server cannot modify cookies after HTTP headers have been sent.

Comment: getting this error at FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

Comment: how to  setting the cookie value before redirection to avoid this error.@testuser

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[RequireHttps]` attribute on your controller to do what you are asking. I would however suggest that since you already have a SSL certificate, just make all of your transactions HTTPS.

The reason for my suggestion is once a user has authenticated, the auth cookie will be sent with every HTTP request. If you then move away from a controller with the HTTPS requirement, a [man in the middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) is a potential vulnerability. Anyone able to sniff a users HTTP traffic could potentially hijack their session by stealing the cookie.

To force HTTPS across the entire site, in Global.asax add this line to the `RegisterGlobalFilters` method

```
filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
```

Comment: i used [RequireHttps] attribute at controller but there is error

Comment: i dont have the RegisterGlobalFilters method in Global.asax ,can u please post that code, it will helpfull for me@james

Comment: [The accepted answer on this stack question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671445/invalid-arguments-error-in-global-asax-in-mvc) is pretty much what you need (I don't have access to my source right now to post my own)

Comment: if i was adding  filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute()); for RegisterGlobalFilters, and [RequireHttps] attribute on controller,it will redirect with the https://....,but  website was not available,please help me @james

Comment: You would add that filter in place of using an attribute on the Controller. It would mean the entire site is https

Comment: still same problem, how can i apply for  only one controller

Comment: i want to redirect only signin and registration pages from http to https,both ActionResult are in same controller, how can i do this , please help me@james

Comment: Take the code noted in your question out of the method. Apply `RequireHttps` attribute to the Controller.